# How to get 0.0 value from oracle Query

Tags: oracle

I have a Query :

```
Select 0.0 from dual
```

The result of the Query is 0, But I want 0.0(Decimal) as the value.

Comment: Do you want the query to return a number?  Or a string formatted in a particular way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `to_char` to convert to a string, and then you have full control over formatting.

However, it is better to keep the data type in the result set, and only format in the reporting tool. There are several reasons why that is "better" - for example, in the output, numbers are right-aligned while strings are left-aligned; also, you can still order by the numeric order of values (if you convert to string and order by the result, the ordering will not be numeric ordering), etc.

For example, in SQL*Plus you could issue the following SQL*Plus command, which only affects the displayed value (while the query still returns a number, not a string):

```
SQL> column val format 999990.9     -- SQL*Plus command (no semicolon needed!)
SQL> select 0 as val from dual;     -- SQL statement

      VAL
---------
      0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select to_char(0, '999999990.9') from dual
```